# Raphael animateWith - origin of animation?

Tags: svg, raphael

Is there any way in which I can animate a certain Raphael element around a different element's origin?
For example, in the fiddle below, there is a larger gray rectangle and a smaller blue square.  When i click the red or green box, both images rotate either clockwise or counterclockwise.
I want the blue square to not only rotate by 90 degrees, but also to translate smoothly so it looks like it is sitting in the corner of the gray rectangle.

```
anim = Raphael.animation({transform: "r"+(spincount+90)}, 500 );
big.animate(anim);
small.animateWith(big, animParam , anim);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nUXVz/

The only thing I can think of is either I am not using the animateWith() method properly, or in my animation, i need to apply some sort of translation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tinkering around for a couple hours, I managed to get what I wanted.

http://jsfiddle.net/nUXVz/1/

To get what I was going for, I ended up adding a translation to the animation.  So I translated from the middle of the larger gray rectangle ( coordinate+(length/2) for both x and y directions ).

```
anim = Raphael.animation({transform: "r"+(spincount+90)+","+axisX+","+axisY}, 500 );
```

If anyone else has any further questions or an easier solution feel free to post.

Comment: In Raphael, while rotating an element, we may optionally set the center of rotation at any point in the plane. So, you have taken the best way to achieve the desired output. Thus, actually, you are not "adding a translation to the animation", but setting a custom center of rotation. The default center of rotation is the geometric center of the element itself.

Comment: Check http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.rotate and
http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform